# NSURLSessionDelegate not being called

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlsession

Trying to implement NSURLSession delegates but they aren't being called. 
Data is being returned but the delegates aren't being called.

Header:

```
@interface APIClient : NSObject <NSURLSessionDelegate>
```

Method:

```
-(void)getAllPeopleWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))completionHandler 
{
   self.apiURL =@"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/fb5ae838b8d752c393db/raw/gistfile1.json";
   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
   NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
   session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

   NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
   [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.apiURL]
       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
           NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
           NSMutableArray *people = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
           for (NSDictionary *personAttributes in json) {
               [people addObject:[Person personWithAttributes:personAttributes]];
           }

       completionHandler(people);

   }];
   [dataTask resume];

}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask     didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
   NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the receiver thread exist after asynchronious session task scheduled.